# Is there a mapping available between unicode characters and the X11/xkb/symbols keyboard layout key names (like odiaresis,..)?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, key, special-characters, x11

In X11/xkb/symbols I find files for defining a keyboard layout. If I take the french (fr) for example I see which letters are assigned to which Key. This is clear for me if I have one character like a number or a character.
But there are also strings(?) like "ampersand","apostrophe",...

```
name[Group1]="French";

key <AE01>  { [ ampersand,          1,  onesuperior,   exclamdown ] };
key <AE02>  { [    eacute,          2,   asciitilde,    oneeighth ] };
key <AE03>  { [  quotedbl,          3,   numbersign,     sterling ] };
key <AE04>  { [apostrophe,          4,    braceleft,       dollar ] };
key <AE05>  { [ parenleft,          5,  bracketleft, threeeighths ] };
key <AE06>  { [     minus,          6,          bar,  fiveeighths ] };
```

**Is there a mapping available between these strings and a character in ASCII or unicode?**
What I am looking for is a mapping like that:

```
 ampersand   &    U+0026
 apostrophe  '    U+0027
 Odiaresis   Ö    U+00D6
 ...
```